# Set breakpoints

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to use visual studio for debugging c-scripts and I am struggling to automate the process. My first test is in vb.net, but I don´t know how to set breakpoints (with my script).

```
Private Sub OpenMicrosoftWord(ByVal f As String)
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    startInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WDExpress.exe"
    startInfo.Arguments = f
    Process.Start(startInfo)
End Sub
```

This is my code to open the project and load the file.
Is there a method or class to force visual studio to set breakpoints at specific lines? There is a command like:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()
```

I need something like break on line.......

Comment: What did you not understand about the information you found when you searched the web for "set breakpoints in visual studio" or the like?

Comment: I did not found an article on how to set breakpoints using vb.net code. The problem is not setting breakpoints with crtl+d+n or something like that. My problem is to open a code file (like c for example) and set breakpoints at specific lines. After this attach the debugger to the process.

Comment: Got a Solution (DTE Object):    main_dte.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add("", basefile, Line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a Solution (DTE Object): main_dte.Debugger.Breakpoints.Add("", basefile, Line)